# Multiple measures mediation analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, causality, mediation

I want to know how to do a mediation analysis with repeated measures. Here is a fake experiment that has the same form as the one I plan to do (using a fake one lets me simplify some weird complications I already know how to deal with):

For each of 5 targets, 100 participants answer 3 questions:

1. How warm do you find this person?
2. How trustworthy do you find this person?
3. How likely would you be to follow this person's advice.

If there were only 1 target, I would know how to do a mediation analysis to (e.g.,) see whether the relationship between (1) and (3) was mediated by (2). However, I don't know how to do it with 5 targets. Clearly, I should not just average together the scores across all 5 scenarios. And I should not treat each case as different (as though I had 500 participants).

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

At least one method for doing this has been published in: 
Judd et al. Estimating and testing mediation and moderation in within-subject designs. Psychological methods (2001) vol. 6 (2) pp. 115-134
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11411437

I haven't yet found a link to code that implements this method though.

Comment: Could you add a brief summary of this paper?